# NullPointerException for progressbar in fragment for Universal Image Loader in onActivityCreated

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-progressbar, universal-image-loader

I'm getting a strange NPE which I'm unable to diagnose. I know that it is coming from referencing my ProgressBar spinner, but I can't figure out why, because I am instantiating it in onCreateView for the fragment.

Below is the code for my fragment. Before you look, I am using universal image loader to load images. The images load, if I completely remove my lines of code for the spinner E.G. spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);  spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 *
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ImageFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private int mImageNum;

    private ImageView imageDisplay;
    private TextView textTest;

    public ProgressBar spinner;

    private String mUrl;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    DisplayImageOptions options;


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment ImageFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int position, String url)
    {
        ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, position);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, url);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public ImageFragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mImageNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1) : -1;
        mUrl = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
        imageDisplay = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        spinner = (ProgressBar) imageDisplay.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



        imageLoader.displayImage(mUrl, imageDisplay, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });




    }
}
```

Please help! I'm not good with fragments, and I can't figure out why it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
imageDisplay = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
spinner = (ProgressBar) imageDisplay.findViewById(R.id.loading);
```

Is this "spinner" a child of your fragment view or "imageDisplay"?

Perhaps, it should be `spinner = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.loading);`

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
    spinner = (ProgressBar) imageDisplay.findViewById(R.id.loading);
```

with

```
    spinner = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.loading);
```

You should find `View` from  inflated view in `Fragment`.

Comment: The guy below answered first, but you're both winners in my book!

Comment: @user2977650 ohhh then i think you're new mate i hope!